# posting messages using Flask + mySQL

Tags: mysql, database, flask

Working on a project where after logging in you can post messages and comments. For some reason I am getting an error after trying to post a message. Since there are quite a few files I will post my github. Any help is much appreciated.

https://github.com/CodingDojoOnline-Python-1/Daniel_Mayle/tree/master/the_wall

Comment: What error are you getting? Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40646257/edit) your question to include a full traceback and a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I am getting the following: jquery-2.2.4.js:9175 POST http://localhost:5000/wall/create 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)

Comment: Please edit your question as the first commenter asked.  You can't expect people to look through all of the code in your repo, especially not even knowing the exact problem you're having.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you are actually creating the database. I will assume it's already created with the `users`, `messages`, and `comments` tables.

You should double check to make sure the tables actually exist with the correct columns. That's most likely where your error is coming from, as the code looks correct. If the tables are correct, check to make sure your password column is long enough to hold the encrypted password, e.g. `VARCHAR(100)` will probably be long  enough.

Lastly, instead of looking in the browser console, read the error output from the Flask server console (that's where the full internal server error message will be displayed). Post back with that information if this answer doesn't solve the issue.